# Pythonic way to write two if-statements

Tags: python, regex

I have two variables that are the result of regex searches.

```
a = re.search('some regex', str)
b = re.search('different regex', str)
```

This should return a re object. If they are not None, I want to use the group() method to get the string that it matched. This is the code I am using right now to do this:

```
if a != None:
   a = a.group()
if b != None:
   b = b.group()
```

Is there a more clever way to write these two if-statements? Maybe combine them into one? I think taking up 4 lines to do this is too verbose.

Thanks.

Comment: To be in line with general python style, you should also do `if a is not None:` rather than `!=`. I think it may also cover some edge cases.

Comment: Can't see how it could possibly be shorter.  What would you prefer to see?  Can you propose some syntax that wouldn't be four lines of code?  Some example that isn't real Python?  Some example from another language that isn't four lines of code?  What do you suggest?

Comment: how are you going to use `a` and `b` after this? I mean, one or the other or both might be "None" rather than a list, how will that be handled?

Comment: "clever" in Python usually just translates to "less readable" and rarely "more efficient". Also the form `if a is not None:` is preferred.

Comment: Can I make a readability request that you do not reuse `a` and `b` for two different purposes?

Comment: reuse a and b for two different purposes? what do you mean by that?

Comment: @passinhi: `a` starts out as a `Match` (the result of a regex), then it becomes the text from within the match.  So, at two different points in the routine, `a` can have two different types (or None).

Comment: @passinhi : added answer to show an alternative impl.

Comment: If you had the reverse, i.e., you wanted to change `a` only if it were not `None`, you could use `a or a.whatever()`. But the converse for this case requires a ternary if statement, which isn't quite as elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't shadow the built-in `str`, and say

```
if a:
```

instead of

```
if a != None
```

Not much else to improve imho.

Answer (score 4):

`a = a.group() if a else None`

Answer (score 2):

If you really must have a one-liner:

```
a, b = a.group() if a else None, b.group() if b else None
```

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, I prefer not to reuse `a` and `b` for both the `Match` object and the matched text.  I'd go with a function to pull out the match, like this:

```
>>> def text_or_none(v): return v.group() if v is not None else None
>>> a = text_or_none(re.search("\d", "foo"))
None
>>> b = text_or_none(re.search("\w+", "foo"))
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor little:

```
a, b = (var.group() if var is not None else None for var in (a,b) )
```

This keeps value of a if it is for example 0. This is the end of your request.

However after some time passed I came up with this suggestion considering context:

```
import re
target = """"Id","File","Easting","Northing","Alt","Omega","Phi","Kappa","Photo","Roll","Line","Roll_line","Orient","Camera"
1800,2008308_017_079.tif,530658.110,5005704.180,2031.100000,0.351440,-0.053710,0.086470,79,2008308,17,308_17,rightX,Jen73900229d
"""
print target
regs=(',(.*.tif)',',(left.*)',',(right.*)')
re_results=(result.group()
            for result in ((re.search(reg, target)
                            for reg in regs)
                           )
            if result is not None)
print list(re_results)
```